# Parse images from page, view them and save selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have written a parser that pulls pictures from a page using the `img` tag, I made a page on which these pictures are displayed, I need the ability to save certain pictures in the database.

I think it will be a button opposite each picture, by clicking on which it will be saved in a certain category.

To download local files, I use CarrierWave, and Nokogiri to search for pictures.

In the console, I can add a file to the database specifying url:

```
Image.new(id: 777, title: 'down', user_id: 2, category_id: 3, remote_picture_url: ('url_to_image.jpg')).
```

How can I now transfer all this to the controller so as not to disrupt local loading? maybe create a new action?

I will be glad to any ideas

```rb
page_action :grab, method: :post do
    unparsed_page = HTTParty.get(params[:parser][:url])
    parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(unparsed_page)
    @images = parsed_page.css('img')
    @images.each do |image|
      img = {
          url: image.attributes['src'].value
      }
    end
    render partial: 'images', image: @images
```

```rb
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
def create
    @category = Category.friendly.find(params[:image][:category_id])
    @image = current_user.images.new(image_params)
    @image.category_id = @category.id
    @image.save!
end
```

My goal is to save certain pictures from the page to the database.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your goal. And what behaviour you expect. What's wrong with a button which call your `create` action inside your `ImagesController` ? It's because without Ajax it's going to reload your page?

Comment: while I formulated a question, I forgot to say that I need to parse pictures in ActiveAdmin, and how just explained to me, that my ImageController is not available in ActiveAdmin. It turns out that I need to write new action in the ActiveAdmin resource, that will save the picture with passed parameters? right?

Comment: clarification: the file parser.rb is located in app/admin/parser.rb